# Need to run directive only if not in a div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I have a directive called `menu` and I need to execute theirs code only if they are not child of menu element.

HTML

```
<menu>
    <menuitem>Test 1</menuitem>
    <menuitem>Test 2</menuitem>
    <menu> <!-- The directive should not run inside of another menu -->
        <menuitem>SubTest 1</menuitem>
        <menuitem>SubTest 2</menuitem>
    </menu>
</menu>
```

Directive

```
app.directive('menu', function() {
    document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(){event.preventDefault()}, false);
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        priority: 800,
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
            var el = el[0];
            el.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(){
                event.preventDefault();
            }, false);
            el.parentNode.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(){
                menu.style.display = "block";
                menu.style.top = event.layerY+"px";
                menu.style.left = event.layerX+"px";
            }, false);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks like you're leaving the element as 'menu', so you just want to skip the event listeners?  Can you just check the parent tag of el?  What should your menu look like, it seems like your sub-menu should be inside one of the menu items, shouldn't it?

Comment: Well menus can be all over the place and can be nested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it makes more sense to have two different directives (e.g. have one `<menu>` directive and one `<submenu>` directive for nested menus).

But if you insist on using the same directive, there are several ways to differentiate a root menu from a nested one (e.g. you could traverse the element's parents until finding a `<menu>` parent or the document-element).

Another approach that I like better (mainly because of its "straightforward-ness") is assigning an extra attribute to the root menu:

```
<menu type="context">
    <menuitem>Test 1</menuitem>
    <menuitem>Test 2</menuitem>
    <menu> <!-- The directive should not run inside of another menu -->
        <menuitem>SubTest 1</menuitem>
        <menuitem>SubTest 2</menuitem>
    </menu>
</menu>

    ...
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
        if (!attrs.type) return;

        // This is a root menu
        console.log('I am executing !');

        var el = el[0];
        ...
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/sKe93/)**.

Comment: `querySelector` will also look among the element's children, so I don't know how you would differentiate the root menu from a submenu that has other submenus.

Comment: I'am sorry figured out too late... :/ Still I would like to not implement any additional attribute (to differentiate from HTML5 standard)

Comment: What do you mean by "to differentiate from HTML5 standard" ?

Comment: My goal is to make it as similar as possible to the HTML5 standard. This mean no additional attributes, no DOM difference.

Comment: Now, I see what you mean. Even the HTML5 standard defines a type attribute to **[be placed on the root menu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/menu)**. So, how about a type attribute ?

Comment: Yeah... I am looking at it, trying to understand the difference, as it seems I will be supporting context only (as firefox do).